# Oracle APEX - how to filter popup LOV on page item

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex21.2

I have a popup LOV on the page that is based on a shared component. How can I filter the popup values based on a changing page item without changing popup source to a query?

Answer (score 0):

Can't test it now, but:

- create application item (in shared components)
- let LoV query reference the application item
- create dynamic action on page item so that - when its value changes - it (re)sets the application item value
- LoV should reflect the change

Comment: my concern is that using page item in a shared component will prevent the LOV from being reusable on other pages

Comment: Shared component LoV would use an **application item**, not page item. You'd just set its (application item's) value based on a page item value. If you don't (on other pages), application item's value will be NULL so you'd just have to adjust LoV's query to work with as well as without application item's value.